# Ruby On Rails + PostgreSQL: How to get all records from table A that don't have association in table B?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have these two models:

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :model_b
end

class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model_a
end
```

And I need to get all records from the table `model_a` which don't have a matching record in table `model_b` - whether through an AR or a raw PostgreSQL query.

What's the most elegant/efficient way to do that?

I can think of only looping through `model_a` and searching for a matching record in `model_b`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a `LEFT JOIN`? Something like

```
ModelA.left_joins(:model_b).where(table_model_b: {model_a_id: nil})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your thought correctly, you can try just exclude ids with relation

```rb
ModelA.where.not(id: ModelB.pluck(:model_a_id).uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of understanding:

```
model_b_ids = ModelB.all.pluck(:id)
ModelA.where('model_b_id NOT IN (?)', model_b_ids)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to try left join and filter on A_id in table b.

```
ModelA.left_joins(:ModelB).where("model_B.model_a_id": nil)

ModelA.left_joins(:ModelB).where(model_B: { model_a_id: nil })
```